# Issue on Checking Multi Inputs Calculation Using each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [this Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/37wt2x9o/) and let me know why I am not able to do the calculation check using the each iterator?

As you can see I tried to use :

```
if (!parseInt($(this).val()) === ((parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.upper').text())) - parseInt($(this).closest('div').find('.lower').text()))) {}
```

Which it didnt work then I used this :

```
if (!parseInt($(this).val()) === ((parseInt($(this).prev('.upper').text())) - parseInt($(this).prev('.lower').text()))) {
```

but still not validating the input?

Comment: What you want to achieve here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if that what you want to achieve, take a look at following example :

```js
$('#test').on('click', function (e) {
    $("input").each(function () {
        if ($(this).val().length === 0) 
        {
          $(this).addClass('input-error');
        } else {

            var upper = parseInt($(this).prev().prev().text());
            var lower = parseInt($(this).prev().text());
            var current_value = parseInt($(this).val());

            if (current_value != (upper-lower)){
                $(this).addClass('input-error');
            }else{
                $(this).removeClass('input-error');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.input-error {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="upper">5</div>
<div class="lower">2</div>
<input type="text" id="txt1">
<hr />
<div class="upper">7</div>
<div class="lower">3</div>
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<hr />
<div class="upper">200</div>
<div class="lower">66</div>
<input type="text" id="txt3">
<hr />
<br />
<button type='button' id="test">Test</button>
```